# making a new user as an openerp client

Tags: odoo

I have setup OpenERP V7 on my machine. I am the admin and I have made a user to be logged in as a client from other machine. But I can not access as this user from other PC. Are there any settings for it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such settings or restrictions, check your firewall settings or URL.